# update a model in the view of a django restframework view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't find examples of using patch to update a partial view in rest framework and it isn't computing for me. Here is my code:

```
class ArworkIsSold(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer
queryset = Artwork.objects.all()

def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
    data = {sold:True,forSale:False}
    serializer = ArtworkSerializer(context={'request': request},data=data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid()
    serializer.save()
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

However, it doesn't update and I get this error:

NameError: name 'sold' is not defined

My model does have sold and I am trying to just set the data in the view instead of sending it in from the ajax request. I just want to hit a view and have it update two fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use undefined variable as a dictionary key. Use strings as keys and then pass dictionary as "data" parameter:

```py
class ArworkIsSold(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    serializer_class = ArtworkSerializer
    queryset = Artwork.objects.all()

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        data = {'sold':True, 'forSale':False}
        serializer = ArtworkSerializer(context={'request': request},data=data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I wish there were some examples of update on the rest framework site.